# Failed to create file - excel to dataset

Tags: c#, database, winforms, oledb

I am using an a .xlsx file and wanted to import the details to a dataset. 
but it gives an error "failure creating file" on  the code  MyCommand.Fill(DtSet);

please see the full code below

```
 System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection MyConnection;
            System.Data.DataSet DtSet;
            System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter MyCommand;
            MyConnection = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + textBox1 + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;");
            MyCommand = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [Sheet1]", MyConnection);
            MyCommand.TableMappings.Add("Table", "TestTable");
            DtSet = new System.Data.DataSet();
            MyCommand.Fill(DtSet);
```

Comment: Do the workbook already contain a worksheet called "TestTable"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`textBox1` is likely to be your TextBox control. To use it's value, you should use the `.Text` property

so, instead of 
`Data Source=" + textBox1 + ";Extended Properties`

use
`Data Source=" + textBox1.Text + ";Extended Properties`